# Is there a limit on the number of measures in Mondrian or more specifically Saiku?

Tags: mondrian, saiku

I have a couple of different data sets for which I am attempting to automate cube generation for Saiku 2.6.  For the data sets with a limited number of dimensions and measures, it works pretty well.  I am however experiencing an issue where Saiku is not showing all of the measures in my schema for schemas with many measures (CalculatedMembers specifically).  In fact, it seems to be that the number of measures (CalculatedMembers) Saiku will show at any given point in time is 115.

I know this sounds like a lot, - it is, but in our case it's necessary.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the schema definition.  For example, if I create a schema with 230 measures, the first 115 will show.  If I then delete the first 115 and refresh the schema, the next 115 that were previously not showing, will be visible.

This seems to me to be a bug in Saiku but I have not been able to pin it down yet.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've finally been able to figure this out and I hope it helps someone else.  Even though the XML is well formed and can even be opened within Schema Designer (Pentaho) Mondrian will not pick up any measures beyond the initial list of Measures.  For example:

```
<Measure name="Cnt - A" column="r_a" aggregator="count" visible="true"></Measure>
<Measure name="Cnt - B" column="r_b" aggregator="count" visible="true"></Measure>
<CalculatedMember name="Sum - A_Rolling_12" dimension="Measures" hierarchy="[A]">
<Formula>sum(parallelperiod([Business date.Time Hierarchy].[Year],1,[Business date.Time        Hierarchy].CurrentMember):[Business date.Time Hierarchy].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Sum - A])</Formula>
</CalculatedMember>
<CalculatedMember name="Sum - B_Rolling_12" dimension="Measures" hierarchy="[B]">
<Formula>sum(parallelperiod([Business date.Time Hierarchy].[Year],1,[Business date.Time     Hierarchy].CurrentMember):[Business date.Time Hierarchy].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Sum - B])</Formula>
</CalculatedMember>
```

works fine, however this does not, in the following case, B does not show as a calculated member:

```
<Measure name="Cnt - A" column="r_a" aggregator="count" visible="true"></Measure>
<CalculatedMember name="Sum - A_Rolling_12" dimension="Measures" hierarchy="[A]">
<Formula>sum(parallelperiod([Business date.Time Hierarchy].[Year],1,[Business date.Time        Hierarchy].CurrentMember):[Business date.Time Hierarchy].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Sum - A])</Formula>
</CalculatedMember>
<Measure name="Cnt - B" column="r_b" aggregator="count" visible="true"></Measure>
<CalculatedMember name="Sum - B_Rolling_12" dimension="Measures" hierarchy="[B]">
<Formula>sum(parallelperiod([Business date.Time Hierarchy].[Year],1,[Business date.Time     Hierarchy].CurrentMember):[Business date.Time Hierarchy].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Sum - B])</Formula>
</CalculatedMember>
```

This to me, seems like a bug in Mondrian's parser, in my mind grouping measures like this is pretty logical and even validates against their schema but it does not work.  Hope this saves someone some frustration.